# average of java.awt.Dimension

Tags: java, awt, average, dimension

Guys sorry if this would sound a bit embarrassing. Can anyone help with how to calculate average dimension of image sizes.

```
Dimension d = new Dimension (d);
//where: 
int width = (int)d.getWidth
int heigth = (int)d.getHeigth

===> image size = (width, length);
//Example
image1 = (200, 350);
image2 = (250, 280);
image3 = (340, 260);
```

How can the average size  be calculated for the 3 images???

Comment: How would you average any other set of numbers?

Comment: Do you mean the average **area** (avg(width*length))?  Or a Dimension (avg(width), avg(length))?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dimension result = new Dimension()
result.width = image1.getWidth() + image2.getWidth() + image3.getWidth();
result.height = image1.getHeight() + image2.getHeight() + image3.getHeight();
result.width /= 3;
result.height /= 3;
```

Basically, just do it like you would any other average.

Comment: ...thought there's a special method for doing this. Thanks a lot!